# Mouse wheel press down and up event

Tags: c#, mouse

So I'm looking for an event in `Windows Forms` what triggers when you press your `Middle Mouse Button` on a mouse. I tried `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` and `MouseWheel` events but none of them worked.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `Mouse Up` event and check if the Middle-Mouse button was pressed.

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("middle mouse button pressed");
    }
}
```

You can do the same also with the `MouseDown` event

I hope my awnser helped you.